# Code for converting unit quaternions into spherical coordinates outputs the wrong result

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I came across this stack overflow question titled [Proper conversion between Quaternions and Spherical Rotation Coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015016/proper-conversion-between-quaternions-and-spherical-rotation-coordinates) but trying the code out, the result did not equal my predictions. My question is, what did I do wrong?

I need to convert quaternions (x, y, z, w) into spherical coordinates (1, ϑ, φ). I found a couple of solutions online, but none seem result in the correct values when I try it out in code. What I tried is converting the quaternions into an axis-angle representation, then trigonometrically calculating the ϑ and φ like demonstrated [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20041029003853/http://www.j3d.org/matrix_faq/matrfaq_latest.html#Q59). My python draft turns out to look like this:

```
def quaternion_to_spherical(qx, qy, qz, qw):

    angle_cos = qw
    angle_sin = math.sqrt(1 - math.pow(angle_cos, 2))
    angle = 2 * math.acos(qw)

    if angle_sin < 0.001:
        angle_sin = 1

    ax = qx / angle_sin
    ay = qy / angle_sin
    az = qz / angle_sin

    theta = -math.asin(ay)

    if math.pow(ax, 2) + math.pow(az, 2) < 0.001:
        phi = 0
    else:
        phi = math.atan2(ax, az)

    if phi < 0:
        phi = phi + math.pi * 2

    print("Theta: " + str(theta) + "\tPhi: " + str(phi))
```

However, the predefined results do not quite match. They should be as follows, with the output beneath:

```
Quaternion: [0.707, 0, 0, 0.707]
Result:     Theta: -0.0    Phi: 1.5707963267948966
Predicted:  Theta: /2     Phi: 3/4

Quaternion: [0, 0.707, 0, 0.707]
Result:     Theta: -1.5707963118937354  Phi: 0
Predicted:  Theta: /2                  Phi: 0

Quaternion: [0, 0, 0.707, 0.707]
Result:     Theta: -0.0    Phi: 0.0
Predicted:  Theta: 0       Phi: /2 or 0
```

Any idea why these values are wrong? As far as I understand, there are no mistakes in the code. Is the math wrong, or are my predictions wrong?

If you care for the reason why I'm doing this, here it comes: I would like to apply [2x2 rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate) with complex numbers to 3D objects in Unity. The plan is to separate the math, which is taken from literature on [bloch spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) from Unity's quaternion rotations. The conversion I'm doing here is the interface between Unity and the mathematical operations.

Comment: How are you generating these test Quaternion values?

Comment: No, I just took some quaternion values from [this simulator](https://eater.net/quaternions/video/intro) Basically, I just calculated 1/sqrt(2)=0.707... for the half-power point and inserted them as the values.

Comment: My suggestion then is that you build the quaternion from spherical coordinates as that's easier to conceptualise, and then you can test a lot easier whether the output matches the input. eg, ```var testInput = Quaternion.AxisAngle(theta, Vector3.up) * Quaternion.AxisAngle(phi, Vector3.right);``` (and possibly plot all three points in Unity)

Comment: The code seems to output theta measured upward the x/z plane, and phi measured from the positive z direction, rotating toward the positive x direction, then negative z, then negative x.